# Joomla 1.7 popup extension to load module inside

Tags: joomla, popup, lightbox, joomla-module

Please let me know, if there any extensions available to display module inside the popup, and popup should load after user login.

Scernario :

- I have opinion poll module, which should popup once after user login into the website.
- I need to specify the module from the backend, either by id or module position.
- The user will vote for the poll after login into the website and close the popup after voting.
- It will be great if it is Non-commercial extensions.

Please suggest me on this.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions and [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com) - do you think your question fits the Q&A character of this site?

Comment: check the Joomla Extensions Directory like everyone else does ;)

Comment: Tried with all non-commercial extensions, please suggest if it can be acheived with some other way?

Comment: Also update your site from Joomla 1.7 to 2.5!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You can load any module inside popup or any other page(in ajax page too).By using the following codes

```
 $document = &JFactory::getDocument();
 $renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');

 $Module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_fmDataGrid');

 $Params = "param1=bruno\n\rparam2=chris";//This will only required when you pass module params through code
 $Module->params = $Params;
 echo $renderer->render($Module);
```

You can create the popup ,The section generating popup content try the above code too.

Hope this may help you..

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create an override for your module (see http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_2.5) and wrap it inside a modal, then set it to registered only. If your site uses Twitter Bootstrap (which most commercial Joomla templates do these days) you can use the markup here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

You'll need some basic knowledge of HTML & PHP to achieve this though.