# Display content of Joomla module in popup

Tags: templates, module, get, joomla

I've just started to work with Joomla and am still trying to work myself through best practises of making custom modules. I'm working on a news tracker creating a list of items from an external XML, generated by a function in my helper.php file.

Based on a $_GET['id'] variable, I want to forward my mod_modulename.php to a different template file (default.php and popup.php). You can guess, I want my module to show the news item list:

- News item title 1
- News item title 2
- News item title 3

Clicking on them should open a popup with only the content of the news item (Title, Image, Content), but due to the framework structure of Joomla and not wanting to put any PHP-code or function calls in the popup.php I'm running into issues.

If it were a component, I could simply make the clickable news titles link to an url with ?option=com_componentname. Because it is a module, this doesn't work (or I haven't discovered how to). Retrieving the content inside popup.php seems messy, and linking to a mod_modname.php 'controller' without a defined('_JEXEC') is just bad practise IMHO.

```
helper.php // retrieves content for mod_modname.php
mod_modname.php // gets the data from helper.php and loads views depending on $_GET['id']
default.php // default view listing the news items in different layouts (list-style, blog-style, etc.)
popup.php // should display only the newsitem selected, not the entire Joomla template
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this without running into bad practises or developing an additional component to this module? (Excluding the debate about using popups)

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
 $document = &JFactory::getDocument();
 $renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');

 $Module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_fmDataGrid');

 $Params = "param1=bruno\n\rparam2=chris";//This will only required when you pass module params through code
 $Module->params = $Params;
 echo $renderer->render($Module);
```

For more [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068065/joomla-1-7-popup-extension-to-load-module-inside/15080277#15080277)